# sshpass doesn't work with SSH ProxyCommand option

Tags: ssh, expect, sshpass

I am trying to automate SSH login for a SSH tunnel using a proxy:

1. I do not want to use the `ssh-copy-id` solution
2. `sshpass` works properly when I set the ssh tunnel **without** `ProxyCommand` option but it doesn't work **with** the option set (Write failed. Broken pipe). The ssh tunnel itself works good **with** that option, asking me for password. Also tried setting the option in `~/.ssh/ssh_config` with no solution. Here is the oneliner:

   ```
   sshpass -p $mypass ssh -fN -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
     -o ProxyCommand="nc -x localhost:8888 %h %p" -R \
     *:$rport:$localhostname:$nport $username@$hostname
   ```
3. I tried an `Expect` script as described [here](http://georgovassilis.blogspot.ro/2012/06/automatically-starting-ssh-tunnel-in.html) with no success. I am new to expect and could not figure out the correct quote escapation because I couldn't find a complex `spawn` example. Here is what I tried with no luck (and some other variations of quotes):

   ```
   spawn ssh -fN -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
     "-o ProxyCommand=\"nc -x localhost:8888 %h %p\"" \
     -R *:$rport:$localhostname:$nport $username@$hostname
   ```

Can somenone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use expect:

```
spawn ssh -fN -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -o "ProxyCommand=nc -x localhost:8888 %h %p" \
    -R *:$rport:$localhostname:$nport \
    $username@$hostname
```

Comment: it works! I have another issue though; when I look in the sshd logs I see that the password is accepted, connection is opened and closed immediately afterwards(and thus the tunnel is not established). If I remove the "close $spawn_id" line, I can't see the accepted password log anymore. Do you have any idea why the session is closed that fast?

http://pastebin.com/vFYimSu0